# Nokogiri syntax errors translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have custom validation for `html_document` column in database:

```
  def html_format
    bad_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_document) { |config| config.strict }
    bad_doc.errors.each do |e|
      errors.add(:html_document, [e.message,e.line].join(' at line: '))
    end  if bad_doc.errors.present?
  end
```

I would like to make translation of returned errors for several languages. 
Error which is returned from Nokogiri looks like this:

```
Unexpected end tag : p
```

I have figured out by browsing Nokogiri documentation that I can check what  is the number of returned error:

```
[1] pry(#<Model>)> errors.first.code
=> 76
```

I have an idea to do translation by given code numbers.
The question is, where can I find full table of errors codes and messages?

Comment: "`end  if bad_doc.errors.present?`" Don't do that. Put your `if` ahead of the block and wrap the block in an `if`/`end`.

Comment: is there any reason to do that? is it against the convention ?

Comment: Look at the code quickly, as if you were searching for a bug or something not behaving right. A trailing conditional, while it works, is hard to see and that makes a maintenance problem, especially when someone isn't expecting it at 3:00AM. They work great for single line commands but once a block is involved I always use a leading `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a look at the libxml2 source code.

this file holds all error-codes: https://github.com/tenderlove/libxml2/blob/ecb5d5afdc8acceba608524f6e98c361fd2ce0e9/include/libxml/xmlerror.h#L174